# Born–von Kármán (BvK) Supercell

Tags: semiconductor-physics, crystals

I have come across in the literature [Born–von Kármán (BvK) Supercell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93von_Karman_boundary_condition), which are described as a unit cell that is repeated periodically. However, say in a calculation that is derived using a BvK supercell, which could obtain something of the form:

$$ \frac{1}{N_{BvK}}F$$

where, $N_{BvK}$ is the number of unit cells in the supercell.

My question is, say we want to integrate the expression above in momentum space, over say the first Brillouin zone only, which corresponds to one unit cell. Does this mean that:

$$\int_{FBZ} \frac{1}{N_{BvK}}F(k) dk= \int_{FBZ}F(k) dk$$

Any information of this would be a great help.